# Django: Use MySQL and ElasticSearch in single application

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-orm, django-haystack

I want to use `MySQL` and `ElasticSearch` using `Haystack` within single `Django` application. Our's application deals with a huge set of relational data with 300+ tables and MySql is the best choice to serve that. But we want fast searching on few columns of tables with 10 Million+ rows.

***Is it possible in Django to use MySQL as primary data storage and use ElasticSearch for search related queries?*** I searched on internet but couldn't find any related information.

- ***If yes***, what should be the approach? Any related links or blogs will be very helpful.
- ***If not***, what should be the alternative approach?

Comment: Yes, of course. Why would it not be possible? What "approach" are you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can configure `MySQL` and `ElasticSearch` within a single `Django` project. Firstly install `django-haystack` and `pyelasticsearch` packages from `pip`.

```
sudo pip install django-haystack
sudo pip install pyelasticsearch
```

In `settings.py`, add `'haystack'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and configure [HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/) like:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://<ip-of-redis-server>:9200/',
        'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING':True,
        'INDEX_NAME': '<name-of-index>'
        }
    }
```

Create a class inheriting `hystack.indexes.SearchIndex` and `hystack.indexes.Indexable` classes. In the below sample code, index in created on the fields of `MyModelClass` model:

```
from haystack import indexes


class MyIndexClass(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    field_1 = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    field_2 = indexes.CharField(model_attr='field_of_MyModelClass_class')
    field_3 = indexes.CharField(model_attr='field_of_MyModelClass_class')

def get_model(self):
    return MyModelClass
```

Refer [HayStack](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/) document for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is absolutely possible. I have implemented haystack with elasticSearch backend and mysql DB myself. Have a look at the haystack docs as a starting point
http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/tutorial.html

Just install haystack, add it to your installed apps. Then you need to define elastic search as your backend.
After that, create search indexes and add the fields you want to search on.
I am not sure what is your confusion, go through the tutorial, its pretty straight forward.